# Filtering out specific email domains from my query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to filter out one specific email domain in my query. I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM CustomerSignup
WHERE SignupDate > '2013-01-01 00:00:00'
```

I would like to filter all the @yahoo.com from my EmailID field with:

```
AND EmailID
```

I'm unsure how to finish this second statement. Any ideas?

Comment: SELECT *
FROM CustomerSignup
WHERE SignupDate > '2013-01-01 00:00:00' and EmailID <>'@yahoo.com'

Comment: SELECT * FROM CustomerSignup WHERE SignupDate > '2013-01-01 00:00:00' and EmailID NOT LIKE '%@yahoo.com%'

Answer (score 6):

Are you looking for [`NOT LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_not-like)?

```
SELECT *
FROM CustomerSignup
WHERE SignupDate > '2013-01-01 00:00:00'
AND EmailID NOT LIKE '%@yahoo.com';
```